# trying to get offsetTop on window.scroll and then traverse the DOM according to the touched slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating one page site and then trying to get offsetTop on window.scroll,  by which i want to traverse the DOM according to the slide.

a lot of tries.. feeling dumb now..

if anyone can help, would be highly appreciable.
thanks

here is the code and fiddle URL:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        var y = $(window).scrollTop(),
            a = $('#first').offset().top - 200,
            b = $('#second').offset().top - 200,
            c = $('#third').offset().top - 200,
            d = $('#fourth').offset().top - 200;

            if (y > a) {
             $('h1').html('This is First Slide');
            }
            if (y > b) {
             $('h1').html('This is Second Slide');
            }
            if (y > c) {
             $('h1').html('This is Third Slide');
            }
            if (y > d) {
             $('h1').html('This is Third Slide');
            }
            else{
            $('h1').html('No heading');
            }




    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A8Hmr/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is correct it's just a miss with the ifs.

I will show the code and explain:

```
var a = $('#first').offset().top - 200,
    b = $('#second').offset().top - 200,
    c = $('#third').offset().top - 200,
    d = $('#fourth').offset().top - 200;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();  
    if (y > a && y < b) {
        $('h1').text('This is First Slide');
    }
    else if (y > b && y < c) {
        $('h1').text('This is Second Slide');
    }
    else if (y > c && y < d) {
        $('h1').text('This is Third Slide');
    }
    else if (y > d) {
        $('h1').text('This is Third Slide');
    }
    else{
        $('h1').text('No heading');
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Hmr/10/)

1) You don't need to take the offset of the slides on every scroll, since they don't change, you can put them outside of the scroll event, that way it will improve the performance.

2) The problem in the code was the if. Since they were all ifs (and not `if/else if`) statements, all of theme were checked if they were true. Meaning that if the first one was true the next one will not be true and it will enter in the else statement automaticaly overwriting the if that was true.

So you have to make them `if/else if` and since once `y > a` become true it will always be true (untill it goes to `y < a`) you must have an additional condition if `y < b` meaning if  `y` is less then the next slide. Ofcourse once again you can use only `if/else` but what is the point in checking 5 things if only one is correct ? Performance should be a main thing in every js code. ;)

**Version 2:**

```
(function(){
    var a = $('#first').offset().top - 200,
        b = $('#second').offset().top - 200,
        c = $('#third').offset().top - 200,
        d = $('#fourth').offset().top - 200,
        h1 = $('h1'),
        textChange = ['No heading','This is First Slide','This is Second Slide','This is Third Slide', 'This is Third Slide']
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var y = $(window).scrollTop();  
        if (y > a && y < b && h1.text() != textChange[1]) {
            h1.text(textChange[1]);
          }
        else if (y > b && y < c && h1.text() != textChange[2]) {
            h1.text(textChange[2]);
        }
        else if (y > c && y < d && h1.text() != textChange[3]) {
            h1.text(textChange[3]);
        }
        else if (y > d && h1.text() != textChange[4]) {
            h1.text(textChange[4]);
        }
        else if(y <= a && h1.text() != textChange[0]){
            h1.text(textChange[0]);
        }
    });
})();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Hmr/11/)

What change here?

1) I wrapped the whole thing in self invoking anonymous function (since it's not a good practice to have global variables).

2) We made a variable outside the scroll event that will hold the `h1` so we don't have to go in the dom on every scroll event.

3) We made an array that will hold the text that will change. (and updated the values in the text scroll)

4) We changed the `if` condition in the if statement to check if the text is already the same so we don't have to change it again. So now it will fire only once instead of firing every time we scroll.

5) We changed the `else` to `else if` since it would enter once the text is the same an jump to the else.

Pretty much that should increase the performance a lot.

Comment: you are right..it has performance issue and not behaving fine.. do you  have any suggestions to achieve this... thanks

Comment: Look version 2, it should perform much better.